# Почему при выполнении OnItemClickListner выдает ошибку?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Задумывалось, что в `LinearLayout` при клике по элементу `listner` будет отображаться разные разметки XML. Но  выдает ошибку, из-за `box.removeViewAt(box.getChildCount());`

Здесь:

```
box=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutBox);
    View view0 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info, null);
    box.addView(view0);
 listV.setAdapter(setAdapter);
    listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    box.removeViewAt(box.getChildCount());
                    View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_about_world, null);
                    box.addView(view1);
                    break;
```

Почему и как исправить?

Comment: друг мой, приводи код ошибки вместе с кодом исполнения в следующий раз, мб у тебя там выход за границу массива?!

Answer (score 9):

Метод `View#removeViewAt(int indexOfChildInParent)` ожидает получить порядковый номер представления для удаления. Вы же ему передаёте кол-во представлений в нём, которое больше индекса последнего добавленного элемента, т.к. индексы с `0` начинаются.

Т.е. вам надо так писать для удаления последнего добавленного элемента:

```
box.removeViewAt(box.getChildCount() -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`box.getChildCount()` возвращает количество элементов в `box`. То есть, например, если их 2 - возвращает 2 (ваш кэп). При этом сами child нумеруются 0 и 1, а вы, например, пытаетесь удалить child 2.

Если по вашей задумке код должен удалять последний добавленный `view`, сделайте `box.getChildCount()-1`. Если нет - поясните вопрос и скиньте стэктрейс ошибки